# How to remove an array value from a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, string, replace

Straight forward, How to remove an array value from a string, Example:

```
var String = "Hi my name is ftk: [2] what is yours? [ And how are 2 5 you? [1] Are you ok?"
var array = [ "[1]", "[2]" ]

---OUTPUT---

"Hi my name is ftk: what is yours? [ and how are 2 5 you? Are you ok?"
```

Basically I want to remove a specific array and only when it's exactly the same word, If it makes sense.

I have tried .replace with global, But I couldn't use an array there, I can only input a specific string like:

```
var string2 = string.replace(/\[1|\]/g, '');
```

See above, I can't remove 2 words at the same time, And it would really suck to manually create a new var to it eachtime I add a specific word to remove, So an Array would be the best.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just loop through your array, replacing each array item as you go:

```js
let string = "Hi my name is ftk: [2] what is yours? [ And how are 2 5 you? [1] Are you ok?"
let array = [ "[1]", "[2]" ]


for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    string = string.replace(array[i], '');
}

console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use a character class to define multiple matches to remove. Then in the callback of replace, check if the match occurs in the `array`.

```
\[[12]]
```

Example

```
var string2 = string.replace(/\[[12]]/g, '');
```

```js
var string = "[3] Hi my name is ftk: [2][2] what is yours? [ And how are 2 5 you? [1] Are you ok?"
var array = ["[1]", "[2]"];
var string2 = string.replace(
  /\[[12]]/g,
  m => array.includes(m) ? '' : m
);
console.log(string2);
```

Comment: @ftk789 I have updated the code with a check for the matched value in the array.

Comment: Your code is leaving some square brackets in, the OP seemed to want to remove exactly what was in his array (including the brackets)

Comment: @AdamPearson Exactly what i wanted, But Thank you very much for the answer as well, I appreciate it.

Comment: @AdamPearson Ow yes, the match should not be indexed.